# PHP Mailer Mails getting repeated for every user I send mails to

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have this code for sending mails using PHPMailer. The problem is that mails are getting repeated with my current code. It goes in this format.

Mail Sends To:

```
user@gmail.com (1st go)
user1@gmail.com, user@gmail.com (2nd go)
user2@gmail.com, user1@gmail.com, user@gmail.com (3rd go)
user3@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com, user1@gmail.com, user@gmail.com (4th go)
```

....and so on.

I think this is because of my while loop logic. What can be the other way to send bulk email to members in my database just once without getting repeated?

Here is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Host = $mainf['set_smtp_host'];
$mail->Port = $mainf['set_smtp_port'];
$mail->SMTPSecure = $mainf['set_smtp_security'];
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $mainf['set_smtp_uname'];
$mail->Password = $mainf['set_smtp_pass'];
$mail->setFrom($mainf['set_noreply_email'], $mainf['set_site_name']);
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Subject = $sub;
$mail->Body    = $mail_msg;

$emails = $pdo->prepare("SELECT mem_name, mem_email FROM members WHERE mem_email_verified = 'yes' ORDER BY mem_id ASC LIMIT 5");
$emails-> execute();

while($u = $emails->fetch()){
  $mail->addAddress($u['mem_email'], $u['mem_name']);
  $send = $mail->Send();
}

if($send){
  $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Mail sent to all members successfully.</div>";
}else{
  $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Mail Server Error! Please refresh the page and try again.</div>";
}
```

Also, in the mailbox I can see who are the others to whom the mail was sent to. Can I add BCC option to send bulk emails just once without getting it repeated for anyone?

Answer (score 3):

```
// option 1
while($u = $emails->fetch()){
  $mail->addAddress($u['mem_email'], $u['mem_name']);
  $send = $mail->Send();
  $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); // reset the `To:` list to empty

}

// option 2
while($u = $emails->fetch()){
  $mail->addAddress($u['mem_email'], $u['mem_name']);
  $mail->AddBCC($u[0]);
}

$mail->send();
```

Comment: Please check your code for `$row` thing... I know where you copied this answer from. I read that article too. If you understand please explain the application of `$row[0]` here (which in my case should be `$u` I guess).

Comment: Please tell me what is the application of `$u[0]` here? How does it work?

Comment: `$u[0]` contains the first element of the `$u` array, which in this case will be the `mem_name` field, which is probably not what was intended. There's no need to pass addresses into both `addAddress` **and** `addBCC` - the second snippet should only call `addBCC`.

Comment: so if I use 2nd snippet then should I use `$u[1]` or should I just replace `SELECT mem_name, mem_email` to `SELECT mem_email, mem_name` ?